# why https_proxy uses http url

Tags: http, encryption, https, proxy

Most proxy providers state they support https but then only have a http url to connect therefore you end up setting both http_proxy and https_proxy variables to an http:// url.
eg.

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://10.10.10.10:50100"
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://10.10.10.10:50100"
```

Does this mean that the request to the proxy service is in plain text then encrypted to the forwarded url, or the other way around. or just not encrypted at all.
Does anyone have any recommendations of proxy services that sell static ip addresses with an https:// url to connect to?
Thanks

I was expecting to assign http_proxy to an http:// url and https_proxy to an https:// url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` refer to which HTTP requests should be redirected to a proxy.

- `HTTP_PROXY` is the configuration for all HTTP requests - it affects only requests that use an URL like `http://...`
- `HTTPS_PROXY` is the configuration for all HTTPS requests - it affects only requests that use an URL like `https://...`

The proxy URL itself can again be `http://` or `https://`.

In your case it is `http://10.10.10.10:50100`. This means the "proxy-tunnel" from your application to the proxy server uses HTTP - thus without HTTPS protection. But the request itself can be HTTPS protected (if it is an HTTPS request).

So if the proxy would use an HTTPS URL and your request is an HTTPS request, then between your application and the proxy server the request will be protected twice, first by the request HTTPS tunnel and second by the PROXY HTTPS tunnel.

Comment: Great, thank you @Robert, I was afraid that even an https request to an http url would not be protected.